# can I store rrd files generated by ganglia in diffetent machine

Tags: ganglia, rrd

Hi I want to change the value of 'rrd_rootdir' as followw

**/etc/ganglia/gmetad.conf**

```
rrd_rootdir = 'storage machine ip/some/path/'

default rrd_rootdir = '/var/lib/ganglia/rrds'
```